# Docker failed to install img2pdf specifically permission denied on python3-pkg-resources

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have a docker file like this

```
FROM node:18
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install img2pdf
RUN apt-get -y install dcmtk

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn global add pm2 -g

COPY . .
```

which working smoothly on my mac m1.

But when deploying it to ubuntu 22 machine,
it failed with bunch of permission denied python3-related issue

[image]

I've tried bunch of things including reiinstall python3 and python3-pkg-resources, which make my dockerfile now looks like this

```
FROM node:18
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y reinstall python3
RUN apt-get -y reinstall python3-pkg-resources
RUN apt-get -y install img2pdf
RUN apt-get -y install dcmtk

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn global add pm2 -g

COPY . .
```

now show this error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge around docker and computer CPU.
But so far my problem happens when I run the docker on intel machine. Now I move my production server using AMD vCPU. it run as local

Would be lovely if anyone have reference the reason for it. and what people could do